# What's the difference with using get_best_hyperparameters() to generate model and get_best_models()?

Tags: keras, keras-tuner

After searching hyperparameters, I tried two way to get best model.

One way is using `tuner.get_best_hyperparameters()` to generate the model as shown in code snippet "A".

Another is using `tuner.get_best_models()` directly as shown in code snippet "B".

Then I use these two model to predict the same data, the prediction results are quite different.

Why? What's the difference between these two models?

A：

```
tuner.search(x_train, y_train)
best_hps=tuner.get_best_hyperparameters(1)[0]
best_model_params = build_model(best_hps)
best_model_params.fit(X, Y)
best_model_params.save("best_model_params_2")
```

B:

```
tuner.search(x_train, y_train)
models = tuner.get_best_models(num_models=1)
best_model = models[0]
best_model.fit(X, Y)
best_model.save("best_model_2")
```

Comment: Not that this an answer, but on pyimagesearch tutorial on keras tuner they use the option A: https://pyimagesearch.com/2021/06/07/easy-hyperparameter-tuning-with-keras-tuner-and-tensorflow/

Answer (score 1):

Not that this is a definitive answer, as I am not sure of the differences here, but it is based on the official docs and a tutorial. From the [keras-tuner "Getting started"](https://keras.io/guides/keras_tuner/getting_started/#retrain-the-model) and from the [PyImageSearch tutorial on keras-tuner](https://pyimagesearch.com/2021/06/07/easy-hyperparameter-tuning-with-keras-tuner-and-tensorflow/), both use option A.

For example, on the official keras-tuner tutorial search for parameters on a subset of the data and train the final model as following:

```
# Get the top 2 hyperparameters.
best_hps = tuner.get_best_hyperparameters(2)
# Build the model with the best hp.
model = build_model(best_hps[0])
# Fit with the entire dataset.
x_all = np.concatenate((x_train, x_val))
y_all = np.concatenate((y_train, y_val))
model.fit(x=x_all, y=y_all, epochs=1)
```

On the PyImageSearch tutorial they do the following:

```
# build the best model and train it
model = tuner.hypermodel.build(bestHP)
H = model.fit(x=trainX, y=trainY,
    validation_data=(testX, testY), batch_size=config.BS,
    epochs=config.EPOCHS, callbacks=[es], verbose=1)
# evaluate the network
predictions = model.predict(x=testX, batch_size=32)
...
```

Interestingly, on the later, they use `tuner.hypermodel.build` directly from the tuner class, which is only shown in the API documentation.

The confusing thing is whether the best found is trained or untrained. [Model is untrained](https://keras.io/api/keras_tuner/tuners/base_tuner/#getbesthyperparameters-method), as per keras-tuner documentation, it shows the following example for the `get_best_hyperparameters` method:

> Returns the best hyperparameters, as determined by the objective.
>
> This method can be used to reinstantiate the (**untrained**) best model
> found during the search process.
>
> Example

```
best_hp = tuner.get_best_hyperparameters()[0]
model = tuner.hypermodel.build(best_hp)
```

However, on the `get_best_models` [documentation](https://keras.io/api/keras_tuner/tuners/base_tuner/#getbestmodels-method) says it returns "List of **trained** model instances sorted from the best to the worst", but

> For best performance, it is recommended to retrain your Model on the
> full dataset using the best hyperparameters found during search, which
> can be obtained using tuner.get_best_hyperparameters(). The models are
> loaded with the weights corresponding to their best checkpoint (at the
> end of the best epoch of best trial).